# Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mkdir"

Tags: maven, ant, maven-3

I am trying to build maven project.I am getting following error. The complete stack trace is below

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (rpmbuild) on project ers: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERROR] C:\Users\XYZ-PC\git\ers\target\rpm-spec-template\rpmbuild.xml:4: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mkdir": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<ant antfile="C:\Users\XYZ-PC\git\ers\target/rpm-spec-template/rpmbuild.xml"/>... @ 4:93 in C:\Users\XYZ-PC\git\ers\target\antrun\build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I have tried searching out this problem but all I found is that may be its JRE problem, I have checked and made sure that my source is using JDK not JRE.

I am stuck and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this something to do with building RPMs?  RPMs are generally used on Linux, and while it is apparently possible to use them on Windows as well (I haven't done so myself), you will need Cygwin installed.  I imagine you will need to run maven from within Cygwin.  Do you have Cygwin installed?  Do you get the same message running maven from within Cygwin?

Comment: @LukeWoodward yeah actually I am trying to build RPM.I have tried Cygwin, but the error remains the same.

Comment: I suggest you talk to the person that wrote your rpmbuild xml file. You may need to run this build on the target operating system for the RPM.